# Access files from folder outside of $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags in MWAA airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I am executing dbt cli commands using Airflow(using dbt.cli.main from dbt documentation) in my airflow tasks.
If i keep dbt project folder inside $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags folder of Aws MWAA airflow,it gives "Oserror 30(Read only File system)".Reason is dbt command tries to create new folder inside dags/ which is not allowed as $AIRFLOW_HOME is read only.

So,can we access files/folders outside dags/ folder or access folders on different AWS S3 bucket compared to bucket used for storing MWAA airflow files?
I need to access these folders inside my Airflow tasks.

Thank You.

Comment: Not sure if you can access other part of the bucket that aren't map by MWAA (dags, startup & plugins path). To avoid the problem of permission, you can use the flags --target-path & --logs-path to write in the /tmp of the instance in wich Airflow is running.